# How to know, what android Dialog is on screen?

Tags: android, dialog

I have two or more android [dialogs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html). All of them was shown, but one dialog overlaps another. 
How to know, what dialog is on screen? 
Like this:

```
dialog1.show();
dialog2.show();
// dialog1.isOnScreen() == false; dialog2.isOnScreen() == true; 
// Because dialog2 overlaps dialog1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem:

```
    public static boolean isActiveDialog(Dialog dialog) {
    if (!dialog.isShowing())
        return false;

    Window dialogWindow = dialog.getWindow();
    if (dialogWindow != null) {
        View decorView = dialogWindow.getDecorView();
        if (decorView != null)
            return decorView.hasWindowFocus();
    }
    return false;
}
```

But if the application is not on a screen, the function will return "false".

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to know what current View has focus.

You can use `getCurrentFocus()`

Continue reading [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCurrentFocus%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Dialog has an `isShowing()` method that should return if the dialog is currently visible. So you can use that to see if a dialog is showing or dismissed.

In your case code snippet will be(may not be perfect solution),

```
if(dialog1.isShowing())
{

}
else if(dialog2.isShowing())
{
}
```

Comment: Both of my dialogs return "true" when I call isShowing(), because they are shown, but the first dialog overlaps the second one.

Comment: @vitkt can you put screen shots plz.It will help to know real problem.